# Recursive Lambda Functions for Cartesian Products in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, recursion, lambda

### Background:

For Learning Purposes, can someone please breakdown the following formula and help me understand how this works? I am wanting to learn the code pattern to create a cartesian product array (ie. a normalised array with every combination of N columns). From what I can see, its a lot of recursive lambda's being used, but I just cant wrap my mind around how it works, so hoping that someone can explain this to me.

### Code Sample:

This is from the original source [here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/86711/combine-two-columns-into-a-list-of-all-possible-combinations-of-entries) - please scroll down to the section that says "*Update April 2023*"

```
=let( 
  table, A2:C, 
  blank, iferror(1/0), 
  first_, lambda(array, tocol(choosecols(array, 1), true)), 
  rest_, lambda(n, choosecols(table, sequence(1, columns(table) - n, n + 1))), 
  wrap_, lambda(array, wrapCount, wraprows(tocol(array, 1), wrapCount)), 

  cartesian_, lambda(a, b, wrap_( 
    byrow(a, lambda(row, 
      reduce(blank, sequence(rows(b)), lambda(acc, i, 
        { acc, row, chooserows(b, i) } 
      ) ) 
    ) ), 
    columns(a) + columns(b) 
  ) ), 

  iterate_, lambda( 
    self, a, b, if(iserror(b), a, 
      self(self, cartesian_(a, first_(b)), rest_(columns(a) + 1)) 
    ) 
  ), 

  iterate_(iterate_, first_(table), rest_(1)) 
)
```

### Input Data:

*Below table is from columns A -> C (as per code above, see "Table" Variable of Lambda)*

| Product | Country | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ABC001 | UK | 9/4/2023 |
|  | US | 9/11/2023 |
|  | AU | 9/18/2023 |
|  |  | 9/25/2023 |

### Output Data:

| Product | Country | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ABC001 | UK | 9/4/2023 |
| ABC001 | UK | 9/11/2023 |
| ABC001 | UK | 9/18/2023 |
| ABC001 | UK | 9/25/2023 |
| ABC001 | US | 9/4/2023 |
| ABC001 | US | 9/11/2023 |
| ABC001 | US | 9/18/2023 |
| ABC001 | US | 9/25/2023 |
| ABC001 | AU | 9/4/2023 |
| ABC001 | AU | 9/11/2023 |
| ABC001 | AU | 9/18/2023 |
| ABC001 | AU | 9/25/2023 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, let’s take a moment to thank goodness for the [LET function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/13190535?hl=en) that allows us to use named expressions. Without it, this business would have to be written like this with every named expression replaced with its definition:

```
=lambda(self, a, b, 
  if(iserror(b), a, self(self, lambda(a, b, lambda(array, wrapCount, wraprows(tocol(array, 1), wrapCount))
     (byrow(a, lambda(row, reduce(iferror(1/0), sequence(rows(b)),
       lambda(acc, i, {acc, row, chooserows(b, i)})))), columns(a) + columns(b)))
        (a,lambda(array, tocol(choosecols(array, 1), true))(b)), 
          lambda(n, choosecols(A2:C, sequence(1, columns(A2:C) - n, n + 1)))(columns(a) + 1))))
 (lambda(self, a, b, 
   if(iserror(b), a, self(self, lambda(a, b, lambda(array, wrapCount, wraprows(tocol(array, 1), wrapCount))
      (byrow(a, lambda(row, reduce(iferror(1/0), sequence(rows(b)), 
        lambda(acc, i, {acc, row, chooserows(b, i)})))), columns(a) + columns(b)))
         (a, lambda(array, tocol(choosecols(array, 1), true))(b)), 
           lambda(n, choosecols(A2:C, sequence(1, columns(A2:C) - n, n + 1)))(columns(a) + 1)))), 
  lambda(array, tocol(choosecols(array, 1), true))(A2:C), 
   lambda(n, choosecols(A2:C, sequence(1, columns(A2:C) - n, n + 1)))(1))
```

That said, let's now look at each named expression within the [LET function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/13190535?hl=en)  to see what they do, and how this overall formula comes together to produce its result.

**table** - `A2:C` - This is nothing more than a [specified range](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/63175?hl=en) of cells. In this case, it starts at the second row of column A, and since no row is specified in the second argument, it continues all the way to the end of column C.

**blank** - `iferror(1/0)` - The [IFERROR formula](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093304?hl=en) uses the syntax `IFERROR(test_value, [value_if_error])` Where the first argument is the test expression, and the second argument is what to return if the test expression evaluates to `True`. The second argument is optional, and since it isn’t used in this case, the result will be a blank cell being returned if the test condition evaluates to `True`. Since the first argument in this case is `0/1`, the error `#DIV/0` is going to occur no matter what, and consequently, a blank value will be always be returned. As we will see later, this is going to be used in the `cartesian_` function to create a “blank” accumulator starting point.

**first_** - `lambda(array, tocol(choosecols(array, 1), true))` - Ultimately, this will be either be the first column of the table during the first iteration of the `iterate_` function, or it will be the first column of the remaining columns from the `_rest` function during all subsequent iterations. Before we go any further, let's explain the [LAMBDA function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12508718?hl=en) because we'll be seeing it a lot. It is a way to create a formula expression where variables are created in the first and middle arguments with *last* argument being reserved for the expression that uses the variables. In this example, the variable is `array`, and the expression is  `tocol(choosecols(array, 1), true)`. The [TOCOL function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/13187258?hl=en) takes three arguments: an array or a range of cells, an optional integer argument that specifies what to ignore that if left out will default to ignore nothing, and a Boolean argument to determine whether or not to scan by column or row with the default being scan by row. In this case, nothing is ignored *[because the second argument is blank]*, and the scan method is by column *[because the third argument is* `true`*].* The first argument of the [TOCOL function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/13187258?hl=en) *[array or range]* is specified using a nested function:  `choosecols(array, 1)`. The [CHOOSECOLS function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/13197914?hl=en) is pretty straightforward. The first argument is a range of cells, and each additional argument is the number of a column to return from that range of cells. It is not zero indexed, so 1 represents the very first column of the array. ***Putting it all together:*** the `first_` function takes the first column of a range of cells as an array, and then, the `tocol` function returns it as a single column.

**rest_** -  `lambda(n, choosecols(table, sequence(1, columns(table) - n, n + 1)))` - In this [LAMBDA function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12508718?hl=en), n is the variable, and `choosecols(table, sequence(1, columns(table) - n, n + 1))` is the expression. The columns chosen from the input table by the [CHOOSECOLS function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/13197914?hl=en) will be determined by  `sequence(1, columns(table) - n, n + 1)`. The [COLUMNS function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093374?hl=en) simply returns the number of columns within a specified array or range, so in this case, the range is the entire table which consists of three columns, and the actual [SEQUENCE function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9368244?hl=en) will evaluate to `sequence(1, 3 - n, n + 1)` With this function there are four possible arguments: number of rows to return, number of columns to return, the number to start the sequence at, and the amount to step the sequence by. The last three arguments are optional and all default to 1. Since the fourth argument is omitted in this case, the sequence will step by 1. Therefore, the number of columns to return will be the total number of columns in the table minus n, and the starting point will be n +1. ***Putting it all together:*** If `n = 1` then, in this case, the number of columns returned would be `3 – 1 = 2`, and the starting point would be `1 + 1 = 2`, so the columns chosen from the table would be columns 2 and 3. Likewise if n were 2, then the number of columns returned would only be one, and the starting point would be 3, so the chosen column would be 3. However, if n were to equal 3, the number of columns to return would be zero, which is good because the starting point would calculate to 4, and that’s not possible with only three columns. It should also be noted that unlike the `first_` function that will always return the first column, this one will never return the first column. As I’ve demonstrated above, it can only return the remaining columns. Hence the name *rest,* which we can interpret as the rest of the columns.

**wrap_** - `lambda(array, wrapCount, wraprows(tocol(array, 1), wrapCount))` - First of all, note that this [LAMBDA function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12508718?hl=en) has *two* variables: `array` and `wrapCount`. Both are needed because the expression argument uses the [WRAPROWS function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/13184285?hl=en) which requires two arguments: range and wrapcount, and there is an optional third argument for pad width that is omitted here. The range in this case will be the column returned by the [TOCOL function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/13187258?hl=en) using the variable `array`, but notice how the arguments being passed to this function configure it to ignore blanks and scan by row. This differs from the previous use of `TOCOL` in the `first_` function where nothing was ignored and the scan was done by column. This means that each consecutive row of the single column that is returned will be a non-blank value from each consecutive column in the array. Finally, the [WRAPROWS function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/13184285?hl=en) will then take that single column and convert it to multiple columns. Each consecutive row will become a single row of consecutive columns until the number of columns equals the number specified by the wrapCount variable. Of course, this could seem redundant to convert multiple columns to a single column only to convert it back to multiple columns again, if it weren’t for the second argument in  `tocol(array, 1)` that tells us that we are removing blank values, and the wrapCount variable that could be used to change the number of rows and columns. In the `cartesian_` function we will explore next, we will find out that this is indeed the case, and that the nested [REDUCE function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12568597?hl=en) will actually be encoding multiple columns into long rows that the `wrap_` function will have to unpack.

**cartesian_**

```
=lambda(a, b, wrap_( 
    byrow(a, lambda(row, 
      reduce(blank, sequence(rows(b)), lambda(acc, i, 
        { acc, row, chooserows(b, i) } 
      ) ) 
    ) ), 
    columns(a) + columns(b) 
  ) )
```

Now that we have a firm understanding of all the basic ingredients, it’s time to get into the core function that produces the cross products we need to pair every value from each column with every value of all the other columns. First of all, the reason this function is named `cartesian_` is because the operation being performed creates a [Cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) using the two variables [`a` and `b`] defined in the first two arguments of the [LAMBDA function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12508718?hl=en).

At this point, the outer part of this function will be the easiest to understand. The `wrap_` function we explored above will take the combined rows that are returned by the [BYROW function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12570930?hl=en); it will convert them to a single column removing the blank cells, and then, it will return it to the original number of columns with the wrapCount argument that comes from the last line of the `cartesian` function: `columns(a) + columns(b)`, where the number of columns from each variable are simply summed to produce the total that there will be.

The next part to look at here is the [BYROW function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12570930?hl=en). As a generic function, it’s fairly intuitive in that it simply goes row by row through an array or range, and it passes each row into ***a single variable*** [LAMBDA function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12508718?hl=en) for some kind of processing. In this case, the [BYROW function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12570930?hl=en) is iterating through the range provided by variable `a` and passing each row of variable `a` into `lambda(row, reduce(blank, sequence(rows(b)), lambda(acc, i, {acc, row, chooserows(b, i)})))`, but notice how its [LAMBDA function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12508718?hl=en) can make use of the `b` argument since the the [BYROW function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12570930?hl=en) is nested in a [LAMBDA function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12508718?hl=en) that originally took both arguments.

Inside the BYROW LAMBDA we encounter the [REDUCE function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12568597?hl=en). The reduce function takes three arguments: An initial value, a range or array, and ***a two variable*** [LAMBDA function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12508718?hl=en) in which the first variable will be an accumulator that will update with the returned value from the LAMBDA’s expression and the second variable will be the current input array that is provided row by row from the REDUCE function’s *array or range* argument. In this case, the “initial value” argument of the [REDUCE function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12568597?hl=en) will be the “blank” placeholder value returned from the `blank` function that was discussed earlier, and the “array or range” will be a sequence of numbers from 1 to the number of rows in the `b` range that was passed into the outermost [LAMBDA function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12508718?hl=en). Finally we come to the innermost part of the `cartesian_` function, and that is the `lambda(acc, i, {acc, row, chooserows(b, i)})` argument of the [REDUCE function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12568597?hl=en). This is the interesting part: `{acc, row, chooserows(b, i)}` As the function iterates through each index [`i`] of variable `b`, its going to take the combined values `acc` and add the `row` variable which is actually the current row in variable `a` that was provided by the [BYROW function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12570930?hl=en). Then, it’s going to use the [CHOOSEROWS function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/13196659?hl=en) to add the entire row from variable `b` that corresponds with index `i`. The result will be a long row that starts with a blank value, followed by `row`, followed by `b[row 1]`, followed by `row`, followed by `b[row 2]`, followed by `row`, followed by `b[row 3]`, and so on and so forth until every row in `b` has been iterated through. Then, all of this will be returned to the outer [BYROW function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12570930?hl=en) which will then supply its next row in variable `a` to repeat the process with that row. ***Putting it all together:***, When the [BYROW function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12570930?hl=en) has completed its iterations, the result will look like this:

```
[‘’, a[row 1], b[row 1], a[row 1], b[row 2], a[row 1], b[row 3], a[row 1], b[row 4]],
[‘’, a[row 2], b[row 1], a[row 2], b[row 2], a[row 2], b[row 3], a[row 2], b[row 4]]
```

Note how each row starts with the blank initial value of the [REDUCE function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12568597?hl=en), and how each row repeats combining the `a[rowIndex]` variable with every row of the `b` variable.

Moving further out, the `wrap_` function passes all of this into the  The [TOCOL function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/13187258?hl=en) in a way that removes the blanks and iterates row by row to produce a single column that looks like this:

```
a[row 1],
b[row 1],
a[row 1],
b[row 2], 
a[row 1], 
b[row 3], 
a[row 1], 
b[row 4],
a[row 2], 
b[row 1], 
a[row 2], 
b[row 2], 
a[row 2], 
b[row 3], 
a[row 2], 
b[row 4]
```

Finally, the outermost part of the `wrap_` function uses the [WRAPROWS function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/13184285?hl=en) with the combined column numbers from the  `columns(a) + columns(b)` argument to convert the single column to this:

```
[a[row 1], b[row 1]],
[a[row 1], b[row 2]], 
[a[row 1], b[row 3]], 
[a[row 1], b[row 4]],
[a[row 2], b[row 1]], 
[a[row 2], b[row 2]], 
[a[row 2], b[row 3]], 
[a[row 2], b[row 4]]
```

**iterate_** - `lambda(self, a, b, if(iserror(b), a, self(self, cartesian_(a, first_(b)), rest_(columns(a) + 1)))` - There are three variables in this the [LAMBDA function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12508718?hl=en): self [which is literally the function itself to allow for recursive calls], a *[an array]*, and b *[a second array]*. The expression part is a simple [IF function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364?hl=en):  `if(iserror(b), a, self(self, cartesian_(a, first_(b)), rest_(columns(a) + 1)))`. The first argument of the `IF` is a boolean expression; the second argument is the value or expression to use if the first argument is `True`, and the third argument is the value or expression to use if the first argument is False. In this case, the test expression is the [ISERROR function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093349?hl=en). `ISERROR` will return `True` if the value is an error. Since in this case our test argument is `iserror(b)`, and our first argument is `a`, we know that if `b` fails for whatever reason the function will return `a` and the process is finished. However, if `b` does not fail, then the second argument will be called: `self(self, cartesian_(a, first_(b)), rest_(columns(a) + 1))` Remember that `self` is literally the `iterate_` function itself, so this is a recursive call. During the recursive call, the first argument is still `self`, so the recursion can continue until the `b` variable fails, but the second argument [`a`] is the `cartesian_` function that we explored above using the resultant `a` value from the previous iteration as the first cartesian argument, and the first column from the resultant `b` value from the previous iteration as the second cartesian argument. Finally, the third argument `b` of the recursive `iterate_` function will be the `rest_` function we explored above, using the starting point of the total number of columns from the resultant `a` value of the previous iteration + 1.

**iterate_(iterate_, first_(table), rest_(1))** - Finally, the last line of the formula is actually the starting point that kicks everything off. Here, the `iterate_` function is called with the second argument [`a`] evaluating to the first row of the table, and the second argument [`b`] evaluating to every column except the first column as defined in the initial explanation of the `rest_` function.

***Putting everything together using your input example***: The starting point of this formula would look like this:

**First Iteration:**

```
a = {[ABC001]}

b = {[UK, 9/4/2023],
    [US, 9/11/2023],
    [AU, 9/18/2023],
    [‘’, 9/25/2023]}
```

**Second Iteration:** Since `b` is not an error, then the `iteration_` function will call itself recursively, only this time, it’s using the `cartesian_` function as its second argument. So the second iteration ends up with this for an `a` value:

```
a = {[ABC001, UK],
    [ABC001, US],
    [ABC001, AU]}
```

Since the third argument of the recursive iteration is `rest_(columns(a) + 1)`, and since the number of columns from `a` value of the first iteration was `1` then `rest(2)` ends up returning column `3` from the table as demonstrated above. Therefore, `b` ends up evaluating to this in the second iteration:

```
b = {[ 9/4/2023],
    [9/11/2023],
    [9/18/2023],
    [9/25/2023]}
```

**Third Iteration:** Since once again `b` is not an error, the `iteration` function will get called a third time. This time the cartesian function will add every row from the `b` column to every row of the preceding a column, and the [`a`] variable will evaluate to this:

```
a = {[ABC001, UK, 9/4/2023],
    [ABC001, UK, 9/11/2023],
    [ABC001, UK, 9/18/2023],
    [ABC001, UK, 9/25/2023],
    [ABC001, US, 9/4/2023],
    [ABC001, US, 9/11/2023],
    [ABC001, US, 9/18/2023],
    [ABC001, US, 9/25/2023],
    [ABC001, AU, 9/4/2023],
    [ABC001, AU, 9/11/2023],
    [ABC001, AU, 9/18/2023],
    [ABC001, AU, 9/25/2023]}
```

Since the third argument of the recursive iteration is `rest_(columns(a) + 1)`, and since the number of columns from `a` value of the first iteration was `2` then `rest(3)` ends up returning zero columns from the table since the argument being passed in now equals the total number of columns in the table. Therefore, `b` ends up evaluating to nothing in this iteration.

**Fourth Iteration:** Since the number of columns from the resultant third iteration’s `a` argument + 1 will now evaluate to 4, and since this value is greater than the number of columns in the input table, the `b` variable will evaluate as an error, and the ['a'] value from the previous iteration will be returned ending the recursive function.

Comment: Wow, thanks for this epic response, I am still reading it and trying to process it all, just wanted to thank you for taking the time to explain this, amazing response, thank you!