# Embed SUMIF / Vlookup / Index-Match functions in Recursive Lambda functions in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, recursion, lambda, cartesian-product

### Question:

Following on from this question:
[Recursive Lambda Functions for Cartesian Products in Google Sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77074748/recursive-lambda-functions-for-cartesian-products-in-google-sheets)

How would I add columns in a generative array which looks up values from the resulting array from a seperate data source?

### Working Example:

*Refer to [this](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rKvjXza_tsbSVEb0T3iv3UlYJI7_N9Z6GUmV_PCo2jc/edit?usp=sharing) google sheet for the below data, logic and formulas*

Assume we have the below table as the result (a cartesian product) of an array formula (see "Code Sample" [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77074748/recursive-lambda-functions-for-cartesian-products-in-google-sheets))

| Product | Country | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ABC001 | UK | 9/4/2023 |
| ABC001 | UK | 9/11/2023 |
| ABC001 | UK | 9/18/2023 |
| ABC001 | UK | 9/25/2023 |
| ABC001 | US | 9/4/2023 |
| ABC001 | US | 9/11/2023 |
| ABC001 | US | 9/18/2023 |
| ABC001 | US | 9/25/2023 |
| ABC001 | AU | 9/4/2023 |
| ABC001 | AU | 9/11/2023 |
| ABC001 | AU | 9/18/2023 |
| ABC001 | AU | 9/25/2023 |

Now, the objective is to add 2 additional Columns (Sales and Receipts) to the above array which looks up values from 2 other tables:

***Sales Table***

| Product | Country | Date | Sales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC001 | UK | 9/4/2023 | $100.00 |
| ABC001 | UK | 9/25/2023 | $200.00 |
| ABC001 | US | 9/11/2023 | $350.00 |
| ABC001 | AU | 9/18/2023 | $120.00 |
| ABC001 | AU | 9/25/2023 | $80.00 |

***Receipts Table***

| Product | Country | Date | Receipts |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC001 | UK | 9/11/2023 | 12 |
| ABC001 | UK | 9/18/2023 | 5 |
| ABC001 | US | 9/4/2023 | 7 |
| ABC001 | AU | 9/18/2023 | 15 |

***Final Result***
After joining these tables together the result will be this:

| Product | Country | Date | Sales | Receipts |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC001 | UK | 9/4/2023 | $100 |  |
| ABC001 | UK | 9/11/2023 |  | 12 |
| ABC001 | UK | 9/18/2023 |  | 5 |
| ABC001 | UK | 9/25/2023 | $200 |  |
| ABC001 | US | 9/4/2023 |  | 7 |
| ABC001 | US | 9/11/2023 | $350 |  |
| ABC001 | US | 9/18/2023 |  |  |
| ABC001 | US | 9/25/2023 |  |  |
| ABC001 | AU | 9/4/2023 |  |  |
| ABC001 | AU | 9/11/2023 |  |  |
| ABC001 | AU | 9/18/2023 | $120 | 15 |
| ABC001 | AU | 9/25/2023 | $80 |  |

### Ideal Solution:

I am looking for something that can be contained and included dynamically in the original array formula that generates the Cartesian Product. I dont want a helper style column, ie. where we need a formula in the adjacent columns that does a SUMIFS / Vlookup / Index-Match formula that needs to be dragged down to calculate the lookup on a static formula. I am hoping to understand if there is some kind of design pattern I could learn to dynamically create additional columns in generative arrays that looks up data based on the rows in the array itself.

Stated another way, if the below is the code that generates the Cartesian Product, how can this be tweaked to dynamically add 2 columns that looks up data based on the values of the rows in the Cartesian Product itself:

```
=let( 
      table, A2:C, 
      blank, iferror(1/0), 
      first_, lambda(array, tocol(choosecols(array, 1), true)), 
      rest_, lambda(n, choosecols(table, sequence(1, columns(table) - n, n + 1))), 
      wrap_, lambda(array, wrapCount, wraprows(tocol(array, 1), wrapCount)), 
    
      cartesian_, lambda(a, b, wrap_( 
        byrow(a, lambda(row, 
          reduce(blank, sequence(rows(b)), lambda(acc, i, 
            { acc, row, chooserows(b, i) } 
          ) ) 
        ) ), 
        columns(a) + columns(b) 
      ) ), 
    
      iterate_, lambda( 
        self, a, b, if(iserror(b), a, 
          self(self, cartesian_(a, first_(b)), rest_(columns(a) + 1)) 
        ) 
      ), 
    
      iterate_(iterate_, first_(table), rest_(1)) 
    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
=let( 
  table, A4:C, 
  blank, iferror(1/0), 
  first_, lambda(array, tocol(choosecols(array, 1), true)), 
  rest_, lambda(n, choosecols(table, sequence(1, columns(table) - n, n + 1))), 
  wrap_, lambda(array, wrapCount, wraprows(tocol(array, 1), wrapCount)), 

  cartesian_, lambda(a, b, wrap_( 
    byrow(a, lambda(row, 
      reduce(blank, sequence(rows(b)), lambda(acc, i, 
        { acc, row, chooserows(b, i) } 
      ) ) 
    ) ), 
    columns(a) + columns(b) 
  ) ), 

  iterate_, lambda( 
    self, a, b, if(iserror(b), a, 
      self(self, cartesian_(a, first_(b)), rest_(columns(a) + 1)) 
    ) 
  ), 

   ftable, iterate_(iterate_, first_(table), rest_(1)), 
   join_, lambda(array, byrow(array, lambda(r, join(,r)))),
   jtable, join_(ftable),
   {ftable,arrayformula({vlookup(jtable,{join_(K4:M12),N4:N12},2,),vlookup(jtable,{join_(P4:R12),S4:S12},2,)})}
)
```

Comment: Almost there, the Dates were not converting back to datevalues, so tweaked the join_ variable to this:  join_, lambda(array, byrow(arrayformula(iferror(array+0,array)), lambda(r, join(,r))))

Comment: Additionally, I have applied some error handling on the lookups (with MAP function) to make the usage more generic, see the amended last arrayformula: map(arrayformula({vlookup(jtable,{join_(K4:M12),N4:N12},2,),vlookup(jtable,{join_(P4:R12),S4:S12},2,)}),lambda(vals,iferror(vals,"")))

Comment: @z - I have a follow on question here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/77328439/1185992