# Running Totals by Group in a Generative Array and using a Lookup for initial value

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, lambda, cumulative-sum

### Question:

Building on from this question on Stack Overflow:
[Embed SUMIF / Vlookup / Index-Match functions in Recursive Lambda functions in Google Sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77321118/embed-sumif-vlookup-index-match-functions-in-recursive-lambda-functions-in-g/)

How can I add a running / cumulative total to a generative array, which is grouped by 2 fields (in the array) and also has an initial value looked up from a separate table?

### Working Example:

*Refer to [this](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rKvjXza_tsbSVEb0T3iv3UlYJI7_N9Z6GUmV_PCo2jc/edit?usp=sharing) google sheet for the below data, logic and formulas*

Assume we have the below table as the result of the logic contained in the prior example (ie. A generated Cartesian Product, which then looks up "Sales" and "Receipts" from a separate table. In the shared google sheet this would be the range from Columns Z -> AD).

This table was generated with an array formula as per the accepted answer to the prior question over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77321674/1185992).

| Product | Country | Date | Sales | Receipts |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC001 | UK | 9/4/2023 | 10 |  |
| ABC001 | UK | 9/11/2023 |  | 120 |
| ABC001 | UK | 9/18/2023 |  | 50 |
| ABC001 | UK | 9/25/2023 | 20 |  |
| ABC001 | US | 9/4/2023 |  | 70 |
| ABC001 | US | 9/11/2023 | 35 |  |
| ABC001 | US | 9/18/2023 |  |  |
| ABC001 | US | 9/25/2023 |  |  |
| ABC001 | AU | 9/4/2023 |  |  |
| ABC001 | AU | 9/11/2023 |  |  |
| ABC001 | AU | 9/18/2023 | 12 | 15 |
| ABC001 | AU | 9/25/2023 | 80 |  |

***Stock on Hand Table***

The next step is that we need to *look up the Stock on Hand* (SOH) from a table at the Product-Country level, for a *given Date* (start date). For example consider the below *Stock on Hand Table:*

| Product | Country | Date | SOH |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC001 | UK | 9/4/2023 | 42 |
| ABC001 | US | 9/4/2023 | 35 |
| ABC001 | AU | 9/4/2023 | 68 |

***Cumulative / Running SOH Calculation***

The running Total for SOH is calculated as following:

> Opening SOH + Receipts - Sales

The Opening SOH is the value from the previous record, except when its the first record (ie. the starting week) of the group (Product-Country), in which case it must be *looked up from the Stock on Hand Table*

### Ideal Solution:

I am wanting to avoid using helper columns or inserting any additional formulas in adjacent cells to achieve this. I would prefer that the Running Total be included in the main formula that has generated the Cartesian Product, with looked up Sales and Receipts.

(FYI: For the sample sheet shared [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rKvjXza_tsbSVEb0T3iv3UlYJI7_N9Z6GUmV_PCo2jc/edit#gid=0) I have used a helper column / formula in an adjacent cell (see cell AE5) - but what I am trying to do is have **one** formula that combines the formula in cells Z5 and AE5 to do everything in one array formula.

Stated another way, if the below is the code that generates the table without the joined Running Total for SOH, then I would be looking to just add some extra logic to this formula to add in the running total by group, with the first member of groups looked up from the Stock on Hand Table:

```
=let( 
  table, A5:C, 
  blank, iferror(1/0), 
  first_, lambda(array, tocol(choosecols(array, 1), true)), 
  rest_, lambda(n, choosecols(table, sequence(1, columns(table) - n, n + 1))), 
  wrap_, lambda(array, wrapCount, wraprows(tocol(array, 1), wrapCount)), 

  cartesian_, lambda(a, b, wrap_( 
    byrow(a, lambda(row, 
      reduce(blank, sequence(rows(b)), lambda(acc, i, 
        { acc, row, chooserows(b, i) } 
      ) ) 
    ) ), 
    columns(a) + columns(b) 
  ) ), 

  iterate_, lambda( 
    self, a, b, if(iserror(b), a, 
      self(self, cartesian_(a, first_(b)), rest_(columns(a) + 1)) 
    ) 
  ), 

   ftable, iterate_(iterate_, first_(table), rest_(1)), 
   join_, lambda(array, byrow(arrayformula(iferror(array+0,array)), lambda(r, join(,r)))),
   jtable, join_(ftable),
   Sales, ARRAYFORMULA(iferror(vlookup(jtable,{join_(I5:K13),L5:L13},2,)+0,0)),
   Receipts, ARRAYFORMULA(iferror(vlookup(jtable,{join_(N5:P13),Q5:Q13},2,)+0,0)), 

   {ftable,Sales,Receipts}
)
```

***Final Output***

| Product | Country | Date | Sales | Receipts | Running SOH |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC001 | UK | 9/4/2023 | 10 |  | 32 |
| ABC001 | UK | 9/11/2023 |  | 120 | 152 |
| ABC001 | UK | 9/18/2023 |  | 50 | 202 |
| ABC001 | UK | 9/25/2023 | 20 |  | 182 |
| ABC001 | US | 9/4/2023 |  | 70 | 105 |
| ABC001 | US | 9/11/2023 | 35 |  | 70 |
| ABC001 | US | 9/18/2023 |  |  | 70 |
| ABC001 | US | 9/25/2023 |  |  | 70 |
| ABC001 | AU | 9/4/2023 |  |  | 68 |
| ABC001 | AU | 9/11/2023 |  |  | 68 |
| ABC001 | AU | 9/18/2023 | 12 | 15 | 71 |
| ABC001 | AU | 9/25/2023 | 80 |  | -9 |

Comment: Are you sure you want to use functions to do this and not AppScript?  seems like something that really only needs to happen "occasionally" and not "live" all the time?

Comment: I absolutely want to avoid appscript like the plague here...also solution is 90% solved with array functions, so we are super close to having the ideal solution, which I am sure is possible...

Comment: did you ask Z? From the previous post?

Comment: yeah, Ill see if I can get his attention...